# jQuery .on('change', function() {} nao funciona em select clonado

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

**EDIT:**
Tenho uma aplicação que utiliza a informação de um select para popular outro select utilizando a funçao change do ajax conforme abaixo:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.empresa').change(function(){
        $('.filial').load('filial.php?empresa='+$('.empresa').val() );
          });
        });
```

Segue código onde utilizo essa função:

```
      <select name="empresa[]" class="select empresa" style="width: 30%">
        <option value='00'>Selecione Empresa</option>
        <?php
            $result = mysqli_query(...);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){
            echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['NomeEmpresa']."</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
          <select name="filial[]" class="select filial" style="width: 30%">
        <option value="0">Escolha uma filial</option>
    </select>
```

Esse código estou utilizando dentro de uma função que duplica toda a minha div, o problema que estou tendo é que a partir da duplicação o change não funciona mais no select criado dinamicamente.

Na prática, tenho um select chamado empresa que popula o select chamado filial.
Então quando duplico a div o segundo select filial não é populado com a informação do segundo select empresa, e sim com o do primeiro select.

Segue um print para ficar mais fácil de ilustrar.

[image: print]

Segue abaixo todo o código da página, agradeço muito quem puder me ajudar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Lancamento Financeiro</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/sistema/css/geralincluir.css">
<style>
.card-form {
  width: 900px;

}
.card-form .form-body .row {

  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding: 5px;

}
.card-form .form-footer button {
  width: 120px;

}
    
.card-form .form-body {
  padding: 2px;
}
    


</style>


<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.maskMoney.js" ></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui.css" />


  

<script type="text/javascript">
    
    

$(document).ready(function(){
              $(".valor").maskMoney({showSymbol:true, symbol:"R$", decimal:".", thousands:""});
        });

//script combo empresa/filial
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.empresa').change(function(){
        $('.filial').load('filial.php?empresa='+$('.empresa').val() );
          });
        });
    

//script enter não enviar form
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').keypress(function (e) {
        var code = null;
        code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);                
        return (code == 13) ? false : true;
   });
});
    

    
</script>
    
    <script>

    var origem = $("#origem");
aplicarMaskMoney(origem);


// function para aplicar o maskMoney
function aplicarMaskMoney(obj) {
    $(obj).find(".valor").maskMoney({showSymbol:true, symbol:"R$", decimal:".", thousands:""});
}
        


function duplicarCampos(){
    var clone = document.getElementById('origem').cloneNode(true);
    var destino = document.getElementById('destino');
    destino.appendChild (clone);
    
    
    // pega os elementos "valor" e limpa
    $(clone).find(".valor").val("");
    // aplica a máscara
    aplicarMaskMoney(clone);
    
    


}

function removerCampos(id){
    var node1 = document.getElementById('destino');
    node1.removeChild(node1.childNodes[0]);
}
        

        

    </script>





</head>

<body bgcolor="#F5F5F5">



<br />

<div class="card-form">
   <form action="123.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="form-title">DOCUMENTO ORIGINAL</div>
    <div class="form-body"> 
      
      
      
    </div>
    <div class="form-subtitle">RATEIO</div>
    
    <div class="form-body" id="origem">
        <div class="row" >
          
          <select name="empresa[]" class="select empresa" style="width: 30%">
        <option value='00'>Selecione Empresa</option>
        <?php
            $result = mysqli_query(...);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){
            echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['NomeEmpresa']."</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
          <select name="filial[]" class="select filial" style="width: 30%">
        <option value="0">Escolha uma filial</option>
    </select>
          <input type="text" name="valor[]" class="valor" style="text-align:center; width: 20%"/>   
            <img  src="img/add.png" width="20px" height="20px" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="duplicarCampos()">
            <img  src="img/del.png" width="20px" height="20px" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="removerCampos(this);"> 
    </div>
            
         
      </div>
        <div id="destino">
    </div>
        
    
    <div class="rule"></div>
    <br />
    
    <div class="form-footer" align="center">
    
     
      <button><i class="fas fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;Inserir</button>
      
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Rubens coloque o html no código, está confuso olhando só pra o js. *"input dinamicamente ele não funciona mais"* o que quer dizer com input não funciona mais? o input não tem "funcionamento". Se tiver algum evento associado, precisar associar novamente o elemento novo, se um elemento tem um evento "change" por exemplo e clonar ele, o novo elemento não vai ter o mesmo evento associando

Comment: não é o mesmo problema dessa sua outra pergunta? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/504040/maskmoney-nao-funciona-em-input-duplicado-via-javascript

Answer (score 0):

A pergunta tá meio confusa, mas se você está criando elementos dinamicamente. assinar eventos no load não vai funcionar.

Tem 2 formas de resolver isso:

1 - passar o event para o parent e escopar para o seletor to elemento que você está criando.
$( "selectorpai" ).on( "change", "selector[es]filho[s]", function() {
console.log( $( this ).text() );
});

2 - criar o evento dinamicament junto com o elemento clonado.

Pelo screenshot parece que você tem 3 selects e você está usando um seletor com id. isso não vai funcionar e vai acabar assinando o evento somente para o primeiro elemento. Sugiro que você use um attributo 'data' ou até uma classe css pra evitar esse problema.